# How to extract data point value from table in PDF?

Tags: pdfbox

I am using java library pdfbox to extract text/glyph from PDF along with its other characteristics such as page number, font, font size, left, top, height, width, absY values. Now I need to create a function that would take as input - row text and column text of the table present in PDF and output value. For e.g. I am looking for revenue increase (row text) for year 2019 (column text) from table of PDF. So input would be "revenue increase" as row text and "year 2019" as column text and output would be the value say "8.5%". Here tables in PDF can be border or borderless, spread over multiple pages or even in rotated or newspaper format page. This makes things difficult. So looking for help here on how to extract data point "revenue increase" value for "Year 2019" in this case from table using text characteristics available using PDFBOX library.

Comment: What you ask for has the dimensions of another project atop PDFBox. You might want to look at [tabula](https://tabula.technology/) for inspiration.

Comment: Yes but tabula works on extracting table as whole. I am looking out for method/function which would just return the value that is required e.g. "total revenue" from either one or all the tables of the pdf wherein that text is present.

Comment: Nonetheless, to generically be able to identify table columns and rows, one generally  has to understand the whole table. That's what tabula does quite decently. You can of course wrap the tabula functions to only return a single cell of the recognized table instead of the whole dataset.